# dask timeseries inconsistant results

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a function that creates new columns and data of a pandas dataframe.   I am now trying to move these testing method to dask to be able to test on larger sets of data.   I am having issue finding the problem as my function does not throw any errors,just that the data is wrong.   I came to the conclusion that it must be a an issue with the fuctions I am calling.  What am I missing?   I think its here but if it was, I would think that python would give me an error but its not.  I recently saw that `transform` is not supported.  I also believe `between_time` is not supported.

```
validSignalTime=(df1.index.time>=en)&(df1.index.time<=NoSignalAfter)
time_condition=df1.index.isin(df1.between_time(st, en, include_start=True, 
                               include_end=False).index)
 df1['Entry_Price']=df1[time_condition].groupby(df1[time_condition].index.date)['High'].transform('cummax')
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - what is your data like, what were you expecting and what did you get instead?

Comment: MCVE coming.   The time_condition is a filter of df1 to reduce slice df1 by time. it creates a filter time window for each day of data.  The next line performs a `cummax` function over that time slice time_condition for each day of data. I use `groupby` to ensure that the function 'Entry_Price' is restarts each date and only during `time_condition`